# How to get name and top N values from range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a small leaderboard with columns of names and scores in the following format:

```
Name 1, Name 2

Value, Value

Value, Value

Value, Value
```

I would like to grab the N largest values,and pair them with their name like so:

```
 Name 2, Value 1st Largest

 Name 1, Value 2nd Largest

 Name 2, Value 3rd Largest
```

I've found that the command LARGE allows you to grab the nth largest value in a selected range, but I can't figure out how to pair that with the name at the top of the column. I suspect I can use Query but I am unsure how I would form that command.

Comment: Have you tried making use of `FILTER`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Name 1 and Name 2 are in columns `A` and `B` like this:

[image]

Try this in cell `D1`:

`=arrayformula(query({array_constrain({if(A2:A<>"",A$1&", "&A2:A,),A2:A},MAX(IF(A:B<>"",ROW(A:A))),2);if(B2:B<>"",B$1&", "&B2:B,),B2:B},"select Col1 order by Col2 desc limit 3",0))`

[image]

**Notes**

As long as there is a value in `A:A`, the array `{}` gets the value in cell `A1`, then a comma then the value in each row of column `A`, then a new column with just the value in each row of column `A`:

`{if(A2:A<>"",A$1&", "&A2:A,),A2:A}`

Then an `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` fixes the result to as many rows as there is data in column `A`: `MAX(IF(A:B<>"",ROW(A:A)))`, and 2 columns.

As part of the array, `;` return the data, then adds `if(B2:B<>"",B$1&", "&B2:B,),B2:B` which is the value in cell `B1`, then a comma then the value in each row of column `B`, then a new column with just the value in each row of column `B`.

The date therefore looks like this:

```
Name1, 202   202
Name1, 564   564
Name1, 269   269
Name1, 33   33
Name1, 455   455
Name1, 32   32


Name1, 9870   9870

Name2, 65   65
Name2, 322   322
Name2, 4566   4566

Name2, 422   422
Name2, 45   45

Name2, 5633   5633
```

A `QUERY` around this data select Col1 and orders by Col2 descending. The results in the query are limited to 3 records.

The `ARRAYFORMULA` works down the sheet.

**Alternative formula**

If you want the results in two columns, then use this:

`=arrayformula(query({array_constrain({if(A2:A<>"",A$1,),A2:A},max(counta(A:A),MAX(IF(A:B<>"",ROW(A:B)))),2);if(B2:B<>"",B$1,),B2:B},"order by Col2 desc limit 3",0))`

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much!